# Yum update Error in centos7

Tags: centos7

We are facing error while install or update packages from yum in centos7. Its an centos7 openVZ server. Can someone help to solve this?

```
Running transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 365, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 271, in main
    return_code = base.doTransaction()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 773, in doTransaction
    resultobject = self.runTransaction(cb=cb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 1798, in runTransaction
    lastdbv = self.history.last()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/history.py", line 1268, in last
    ret = self.old([], 1, complete_transactions_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/history.py", line 1217, in old
    executeSQL(cur, sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/sqlutils.py", line 166, in executeSQLQmark
    return cursor.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: trans_beg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error suggests a corruption in your `yum` history database. See this bug report:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699041

The report offers two possible suggestions:

1. The command `yum history new` could potentially fix the problem by building a new history file. The downside is that this command will reset your `yum` history.
2. You could try to remove some history files from `/var/lib/yum/history`, which will revert your history back to an earlier date.